# Postgresql selecting specific set of records based on a field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have postgresql data-set as shown below where a app_id may have multiple record. I need to select all the records for each app_id where bool_flag is true and if a app_id has no records with bool_flag value equal true then pick all records with false value for that app.

Here is the link to available data set
[data-set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XTfF.png)

and this is the desired output I am looking for, thanks in advance.
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTPxN.png)

Comment: This is a community where we can help you with your programming, but this is not a place where we write code for you. Please take a look at this guide to writing a good SO Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.bool_flag
union all
select t.*
from t
where not t.bool_flag and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.app_id = t.app_id and t2.bool_flag
                 );
```

As the description states, it starts by getting all rows with "true".  It then gets the "false" rows where there is no corresponding "true" row.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I tried your suggested solution, it may be due to my limited knowledge, It didn't work. Anyway thanks for your response. With count window function (First comment) I got what I was looking for.

Comment: @ZindaHu . . . Do you get an error?  How does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with `count` window function.

```
select app_id,created_date,bool_flag
from (select t.*
      ,count(case when not bool_flag then 1 end) over(partition by app_id) as false_cnt
      ,count(*) over(partition by app_id) as total
      from tbl t
     ) t
where bool_flag or total=false_cnt
```

Another way with `bool_or`.

```
select t1.* 
from (select app_id,bool_or(bool_flag) as bool_res
      from tbl
      group by app_id
     ) t
join tbl t1 on t.app_id=t1.app_id 
where t.bool_res=t1.bool_flag
```

Comment: Thanks @vkp, your first method worked as expected. I got the result I was looking for. Thanks!!